# Explain the value of $(0,0)$ for $f(x,y)=1+x\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ (where $\mathbb R$ is the real numbers) continuous in $\mathbb R^2$, such that 
>   $$f(x,y)=1+x\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$
>
> Justify the value of $f(0,0)$.

The function is continuous in its domain, and $f(0,0)$ is defined by another equation. What else do I have to justify?

Comment: except $(0,0)$ is in the domain of $f$, so what should $f(0,0)$ be to make the function continuous?

Comment: how is (0,0) in the domain>

Comment: You are misunderstanding something. The domain of $f$ is given, and it is $\mathbb{R}^2$ which does contain $(0,0)$. You are also given that $f$ is continuous on that entire domain. You are also given the value of $f$ on all points of the domain except $(0,0)$. All this information together uniquely determines the value of $f$ in $(0,0)$. Why is that, and what is that value?

Comment: Oh, so the value $f(0,0)$ is just defined by another expression?

Comment: Well yes, that formula you give is certainly not going to work in $(0,0)$ so it will have to be something else.

Comment: So what exactly will I need to say?

Comment: If you edit your question such that it shows that you now understand what is asked, someone might just be kind enough to give a hint :)

Comment: It's done. Just edited it

Comment: You are supposed to evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ (assuming it exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: $\left|x\cdot \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right| \le |x|\cdot \left|\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right| = |x| \implies \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = 1+0 = 1 \implies f(0,0) = 1$.